# link hidden until scroll using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a back to top link however it shows even when the page is at the top

```
<a class="w-toplink active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

I would like it to be hidden until the user starts to scroll the page - is this possible? If so, how?

The other thing that I have tried and tried to do is make the link change on hover with opacity but it doesn't seem to be working - can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

CSS

```
.w-toplink {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: -50px;
right: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top:15px;
line-height: 50px;
height: 30px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
background-color: #333;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
}

.w-toplink.active {
bottom: 30px;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.w-toplink:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        $toplink = $('.w-toplink');

    if(scrollTop > 0){
        $toplink.addClass('active');
    } else{
        $toplink.removeClass('active');
        }
});
```

CSS:

```
.w-toplink{opacity:0; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}
    .w-toplink.active{opacity:0.7;}
    .w-toplink:hover{opacity:1;}
```

**Edit** I've added some extra code for you.

1. .w-toplink is hidden by default
2. When the user scrolls it becomes 0.7opacity (through the class .active)
3. When the users hovers the link, it becomes fully visible (opacity:1)

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
       $('.w-toplink').fadeIn(250);
   } else {
       $('.w-toplink').fadeOut(250);
   }
});
```

And add this to your CSS file :

```
.w-toplink {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This should work, too! I just like to keep these little animations away from my javascript and control them with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like fun...

It is possible you have to simply put an eventListener for Scroll.
which is possible in either vanillaJS or jQuery...

see this for more about scroll: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

```
<a class="w-toplink active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

(Assuming you are already using the jQuery CDN.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("a.w-toplink").hide();
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
  $( "a.w-toplink" ).css( "display", "visible" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

```js
$("a.w-toplink").hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("a.w-toplink").show();
});
```

```css
.w-toplink {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top:15px;
line-height: 50px;
height: 30px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
background-color: #333;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="w-toplink stuff">Back to to top</a>



<p>Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem
  Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...
</p>
<ul>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample
    <p>Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem
      Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample
    <p>Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff...Lorem
      Ipsum and stuff...Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff... Lorem Ipsum and stuff...
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>

  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
    </script>
```

Comment: did you try this? It works in the JSFiddle... you have to make sure you have enough to scroll... also opacity:0; doesn't work with jQuery Show... if you'd like to hide something on jQuery it is best to use display:none; ...

Comment: works thanks! I'm trying to get the icon to change on hover but cannot. I want it to change colour using opacity or something to that effect? jsfiddle.net/uu1ufq20

Comment: to do that you say .w-toplink:hover{ 
background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.4);
} 
on the css..
then on the element itself you can do
transition: 1s all(by default it is already all and then it will activate the hover after 1 second) ease (the type of transition you want)

Comment: That will change the color to some sort of grey I always use rgba colors the a means to what extent it is transparent from 0-to 1.0 and unfortunately you have to always use a 0 unless you are using sass.

Comment: Instead of show(), use addClass('active'). Then, in your CSS, set .active{opacity:0.7;} and .active:hover{opacity:1;}. And you have to add an else statement to the script with a removeClass('active'), so when the users is at the top, the script removes the class 'active'.

Comment: Yes that's true that is probably more what the author would have intended but I think the fade In will probably have the fading animation anyway.